# SML, How to find number of occurrences of the minimum number in a list?

Tags: list, sml, find-occurrences

In SML is it possible to find the number of occurrences of the min number in a list?

I have code to find the number of occurrences of a number but i am stumped on how to find the min and use it to find how many of the minimum num there is.

```
fun occurrences(nil, n)=0
|   occurrences(ls, n) =
    if hd(ls)=n then occurrences(tl(ls),n) + 1
    else occurrences(tl(ls),n) + 0;
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can write a function that keeps track of the min value and its count as you iterate through the list.

We can do this by implementing a tail-recursive function which `helper`, which maintains the value of the current minimum and a count of the number of times that item has appeared.

We can then wrap this in another function `min_count` via a let-in-end block.

For example:

```ml
fun min_count [] = 0 (* the empty list has zero items in it *)
  | min_count (x :: xs) =
let
  (* when we reach the end of the list, return the accumulated count *)
  fun helper (_, n) [] = n
    | helper (m, n) (y :: ys) =

    (* if we find a new minimum, reset the count *)
    if y < m then helper (y, 1) ys

    (* if the current list item is larger than the min, ignore it *)
    else if y > m then helper (m, n) ys

    (* if we've found another instance of the min, add one to the count *)
    else helper (m, n + 1) ys
in
  (* first item appears once *)
  helper (x, 1) xs (* first item appears once *)
end;
```

Comment: Thank you! How would i run this code?

Answer (score 1):

This problem is a good test for using folds on a list.

### Finding the mininum

If we want to find the minimum in a list we need to iterate over the list checking each element against a predetermined starting minimum value. If that element is less than that known minimum, we continue to iterate using that value instead. When we're done, we have the minimum value.

If the list is empty, there is *no* minimum value. If only one value is in the list, the minimum is obviously that. If there are more values, the starting minimum value is the first element.

We can use `foldl` to handle the iteration in this last case.

```
fun min([]) = NONE
  | min([x]) = SOME x
  | min(first::rest) = 
    SOME (foldl (fn (x, min) => if x < min then x else min) 
                first rest)
```

### Finding occurrences

You've already done this, but this can be done in terms of a fold as well.

```
fun occurrences(lst, v) =
  foldl (fn (x, count) => if x = v then count + 1 else count) 
        0 lst
```

### Putting this together

We could use these two functions to find the number of times the minimum occurs in a list.

```
let
  val numbers = [1, 4, 7, 2, 9, 0, 1, 6, 0]
  val min = min(numbers)
  val occ = case min of
    NONE => NONE
  | SOME x => SOME (occurrences(numbers, x))
in
  case (min, occ) of
    (NONE, NONE) => print("No minimum found.") 
  | (SOME m, SOME t) => print("Min: " ^ Int.toString(m) ^ "; times: " ^ Int.toString(t))
end
```

### Can we do it in a single pass?

Using the above approach, we have to iterate over the list twice. This is a more general, but less efficient way of getting both pieces of information the minimum and the number of occurrences of it. We can use `foldl` to get both pieces of information, and it's going to look at lot like the definition of `min`.

We just need to pass a function to `foldl` that keeps a running tally of the number of times it has found the minimum value, and we need to pass it a tuple with both an initial minimum value and an initial count of `1`.

```
fun minCount([]) = NONE 
  | minCount([x]) = SOME (x, 1)
  | minCount(first::rest) = 
    SOME (foldl (fn (x, init as (min, count)) => 
                  case Int.compare(x, min) of
                    EQUAL => (min, count + 1)
                  | LESS  => (x, 1)
                  | _     => init)
                (first, 1)
                rest)
```

With this function defined, our previous code can be rewritten as:

```
let
  val numbers = [1, 4, 7, 2, 9, 0, 1, 6, 0]
  val mc = minCount(numbers)
in
  case mc of
    NONE => print("No minimum found.") 
  | SOME (m, t) => print("Min: " ^ Int.toString(m) ^ "; times: " ^ Int.toString(t))
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that you are supposed to use your `occurrences` function in the solution, write a function that finds the minimum,

```
fun minimum [x] = x
  | minimum (x::xs) = let 
                        val min = minimum xs 
                      in 
                        if x < min then x else min 
                      end
```

Note that this does not handle the empty list.
You need to decide whether to leave the missing pattern as a runtime error, or add it and handle the error, for instance by raising an exception or by changing the return type to `int option`.
If you're taking a course, use one of the methods you've learned so far.

Then you can use that function,

```
occurrences(the_list, minimum the_list)
```